# How to fix "symbol lookup error" in a distributed binary?

Tags: linux-mint, undefined-symbol

I have just upgraded Linux Mint from 19.3 to 20.

I find that archive files are not opening.  More specifically, file-roller is reporting an error:

```
root@Sala:/home/peter# /usr/bin/file-roller
/usr/bin/file-roller: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/file-roller: undefined symbol: archive_write_add_filter_zstd
```

I have removed and reinstalled file-roller both using synaptic and apt --purge but the issue is not resolved.

I have posted in Linux Mint forums and there is no solution posted after more than 24 hours.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Okay, further investigation shows that there are a lot of 'archive_write_add_filter*' symbols in libarchive.so.13, but zstd is not amongst them.  I'm a little suspicious that my libarchive.so.13 dates from Sep 15 2017, but I'm not sure how to find a newer copy which may include zstd.

Comment: Right, I've resolved the issue - for some reason, the old copy of libarchive.so had been installed in /usr/local/lib alongside Python libraries.  Deleting that allows file-roller to run.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue on Amazon AMI that has the latest upgradable version of libarchive set at 3.1.2-14.amzn2 and I wanted to get the actual latest version of 3.5.1.  I was able to resolve it with the help of http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/libarchive.html:

```
sudo yum remove libarchive*
wget https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/releases/download/3.5.1/libarchive-3.5.1.tar.xz
tar -xvf libarchive-3.5.1.tar.xz

cd libarchive-3.5.1
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static && make
sudo make install

cd .. && rm -rf libarchive-3.5.1 && rm libarchive-3.5.1.tar.xz
```

I was messing with this because I was trying to update CMake as well. That continued to fail because CMake is looking for libarchive in /usr/lib64 but it was installed to /usr/lib. This feels wrong. Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

`sudo cp /usr/libarchive* /usr/lib64`